# This of class instance/ object always become undefined after executing experimental class method decorator

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am building a web API using Node JS (Express + TypeScript). In my application, I am creating a Typescript experimental decorator for validation logic which can be applied to my controller's action method/ route handler which is literally a method of a class. But `this` keyword always becomes undefined in the route handler method of the controller class after executing the decorator method.

This is my method decorator implementation

```
export function ValidateRequestAsync(schema: joi.ObjectSchema) {
  return function (
    scope: unknown,
    methodName: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = async function (
      req: Request,
      res: Response,
      ...args: unknown[]
    ) {
      try {
        await validateRequestAsync(schema, req.body);
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof joi.ValidationError) {
          return validationErrorResponse(res, resolveValidationError(e));
        }
      }

      return originalMethod.apply(scope, [req, res, ...args]);
    };
  };
}
```

I apply the decorator method to the router handler method as follow.

```
export class AuthController {
  @ValidateRequestAsync(registerValSchema)
  public async register(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const user = await registerUser(req.body);
    
    
    return this.generateUserResponse(user);
  }


  }
```

When I execute the code, it is validating the request as expected. But when it tries to execute the `this.generateUserResponse(user);` line after the validation is passed, it is throwing this error.

```
this.generateUserResponse is not a function
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is `generateUserResponse` defined and how it `register` being called?

Comment: It is in the same controller class. It a private function.

Comment: The code was working fine if I don’t use decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what happens here is that your this context is being redeclared in the decorator method. Since your method is a block function, it contains its own `this` scope and it might not see a `generateUserResponse` method from your `AuthController`.

Try changing

```
 descriptor.value = async function (
      req: Request,
      res: Response,
      ...args: unknown[]
    ) {
```

to use an arrow function instead

```
descriptor.value = async (
      req: Request,
      res: Response,
      ...args: unknown[]
    ) => {
```

if that won't work. I'd suggest investigating how you instantiate the auth controller and/or consider using `.bind()` method.

Comment: I tried but it still does not work.